# It's possible in asterisk call and let the callee hear a custom message?

Tags: asterisk

I can't figure out how to do a call from my Asterisk and automatically play a sound file to callee , there's anyone who knows some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways -- how thorough of an answer are you looking for?

The Asterisk scripting language (DIALPLAN) allows you to play a file using the Playback command (http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Playback).

For instance:

```
exten => s,1,Playback(/path/to/my/sound/file.wav)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: ok but i want the other party hears the message, as i wrote on the previous comment to arheops, i want to go out with a prerecorded message, like : Asterisk call my mobile, i hang up from the mobile and hear "You received a notification from my server".Don't know how, i thought to originate a call and then let a fake extension pickup the call letting the callee hear the message... do you think is the right way?

Comment: That's correct -- you can achieve this by using a callfile and the code above -- the callfile is what will initiate the outbound call -- then when the call is answered, the code below will run (which plays the message to the person that was called).

Answer (score 0):

If you need "do a call from my asterisk" that can be

1) auto diallout. This require guru level of knowledge to do dialling core, but you can get already designed systems like vicidial

2) manual playback to other party on key pressed. For that check features.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf

Comment: the point 1. it's ok for me, i send originate commands with c# to my Asterisk server,the goal i'm trying to reach is let the asterisk call an extern number where there's nobody speaking but just a prerecorder message like :"you received a notification from my server".I'll check the link you sent me, thx anyway

Comment: You need read more books. I recomend ORelly's "Asterisk the Future of Telephony"